# Why is waypoints not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

On My computer C drive, I created a test.html file and inside it I have

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.5/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#waypoint').waypoint(function() {
            alert('You have scrolled to my waypoint.');
        }, {
            offset: '100%'
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="waypoint">WAYPOINT</div>
```

I don't get the alert popup, yet the exact same code in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ppqbdse7/) works fine. What gives?

Comment: Check the console for errors. You may be encountering security warnings as you're running this code from your local machine, and not under a web server.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan console shows no errors. I even tried the same code from my website and it doesn't work either. A simple `$(document).ready(function() {
            alert('You have scrolled to my waypoint.');
    });` works fine, which tells me jquery is loaded and working fine.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan does my test.html code work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik some browsers don't load external resources (`.js` files) when simply opended by double clicking the `.html` file. Please check, whether there's `file://` in your browser's URL bar.
If so, install [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/download.html) (or something similar, depending on your OS) on your machine, put your file somewhere under `htdocs` and retry.

Also JSFiddle wraps your code in a valid HTML Document. You might add `<html><head>...` to your [HTML to make it valid](http://www.w3schools.com/html/). Especially since you're dealing with viewport scrolling that might be required for the plugin to work.

Last to be said is that the include order of your `.js` files matter, since they're loaded in order. Since waypoints depends on jQuery (as it is a jQuery plugin) it needs to be loaded **FIRST**.

Comment: Thank you, it was the order like you mentioned. Just needed to put jquery first.

Comment: Great! You should still consider following my other recommendations to get good and reliable results.